# Rspec Post wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) Request Spec Time Dependent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method in jobs controller that forces some delayed jobs to run now

```
  def retry_queued
    @jobs = Delayed::Job.awaiting_retry.update_all(run_at: Time.zone.now)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_path, notice: "Queued jobs getting retried." }
      format.json render json: { status: 'success' }
    end
  end
```

Its using a scope.

I am trying to test this with rspec and its given post request way in request spec

```
  describe "POST retry_queued" do
    before do
      @not_running = Delayed::Job.create(run_at: Time.zone.now - 1.hour)
      @not_running.update_attribute(:attempts, 1)
      @from = Delayed::Job.last.run_at
      sign_in users(:jane)
    end

    it "run the queued job" do
      expect(Delayed::Job.last.run_at.to_s).not_to eq(Time.zone.now.to_s)
      post :retry_queued
      expect(Delayed::Job.last.run_at.to_s).to eq(Time.zone.now.to_s)
    end
  end
```

my snippet of routes

```
  resources :jobs, :only => [:index, :destroy] do
    member do
      put :run
    end
    collection do
      delete :destroy_failed
      delete :destroy_all
      post :retry_queued
    end
  end
```

The rspec error is below

```
  1) JobsController POST retry_queued run the queued job
     Failure/Error: post :retry_queued
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

and my link_to to tap it

```
<%= link_to retry_queued_jobs_path, class: "btn btn-default", method: :post do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Retry queued jobs
<% end %>
```

It seems like its asking me to pass arguments to post but I don't have any. I just want my method to get hit. I remember I can just post and not have to specify params in the past but can't remember what I did that is giving me the error that I am getting.

Currently using rspec 3.2

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I am rendering the json incorrectly it should be `format.json { head :no_content }` instead of `format.json render json: { status: 'success' }`

Answer (score -1):

In most cases it's not a good idea to test something depending on Time, 'cause the precision of time measurement exceeds calculation speeds, especially when dealing with fairly complex operations like requeueing a job. I'd suggest trying the `timecop` [gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) and looking at the results.

Comment: The spec passed after I fixed the error. According to delayed job I am suppose to use `Time.zone.now`. I am not interested in adding another library into the app. Thank you for the suggestion.